# Apache Camel : How to move back the files from preMove folder to original folder in case of error

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I have code which uses Apache Camel - The route checks for a file with a pattern in the source folder, It does a preMove of the file from original folder, runs a processor and on success, it moves the file to destination folder.
In case the processor fails, the file remains in the preMove folder and does not get processed at all, as the original route check only the source folder.

I need to move the file back to original source folder, in case of processor failure (in case of a particular exception only). Please suggest how can this be done. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you do this, the error will become infinite..

Comment: I will do this only for a particular exception (Token expiration). Token will get renewed within few seconds, and this file should move to original folder and get reprocessed automatically. Or else, I need the route to retry the same file again after few seconds.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: pick file from original location --> pre-move to processing folder --> do processing --> tokenfailedException --> get new token --> call the same route again --> do processing --> fileNotFound (as the file was moved to processing folder)

Comment: Have you tried to write the file back in an onException-clause?